# How to change form status manually? Or what to do before reassign a form?

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-form-validation

For some reason I have to change a form status manually.

In my case, if form validation failed, I can click a refresh button, and then the form will be initiate again. But the validation failed status stayed and thus caused some problems, so I have to change the form status before reassign it. actually what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Basically in Angular form Validations are Easy Part.

in `app.component.ts` file:

you need to add

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

After That

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],

      firstName: ['', Validators.required],

      lastName:['', Validators.required],

      address: ['', Validators.required],

    })
}
```

In HTML `app.component.html`:

```
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" class="input_block form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button (click)="onReset()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

In Form Submit Function =>

```
    onReset() {
      this.registerForm.reset();
    }
```

That's it. Happy coding